# Converting int to roman numerals, only end if zero entered

Tags: c++

I need to convert int to Roman numerals, my code is failing to compile with mingw using

C:\code>g++ -Wall -o rome_to_int rome_to_int.cpp
C:\Users\vm1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSvDFll.o:task2.cpp:(.text+0x1278): undefined r
eference to `get_int_ref_checked()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Now as part of the code, it must keep asking for input, converting that input untill zero is entered. Once Zero has been entered then it can exit.

I must use code from a privius question which covers the continuing untill which is found in the get_int_ref_checked, I can assume ONLY integers will be entered and nothing else, no doubles nor string of words.

I'm not sure what else to check.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <sstream>

using namespace std; 
int get_int_ref_checked();
string int_to_ROMAN(); 



/**
 Turns the number from 1 to 9
*/
string digit_name(int digit)
{  
   if (digit == 1) return "I";
   if (digit == 2) return "II";
   if (digit == 3) return "III";
   if (digit == 4) return "IV";
   if (digit == 5) return "V";
   if (digit == 6) return "VI";
   if (digit == 7) return "VII";
   if (digit == 8) return "VIII";
   if (digit == 9) return "IX";
   return "";
}

/**
 Turns the number 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90
*/
string ten_name(int n)
{  
   if (n == 1) return "X";
   if (n == 2) return "XX";
   if (n == 3) return "XXX";
   if (n == 4) return "XL";
   if (n == 5) return "L";
   if (n == 6) return "LX";
   if (n == 7) return "LXX";
   if (n == 8) return "LXXX";
   if (n == 9) return "XC";
   return "";
}

/**
 Turns the number 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900
*/
string hun_name(int n)
{  

   if (n == 1) return "C";
   if (n == 2) return "CC";
   if (n == 3) return "CCC";
   if (n == 4) return "CD";
   if (n == 5) return "D";
   if (n == 6) return "DC";
   if (n == 7) return "DCC";
   if (n == 8) return "DCCC";
   if (n == 9) return "CM";
   return "";
}

/**
 Turns the number 1000, 2000, 3000
*/
string thou_name(int n)
{  

   if (n == 1) return "M";
   if (n == 2) return "MM";
   if (n == 3) return "MMM";

   return "";
}


string int_to_ROMAN(int n)
{
   int part = n; // The part that still needs to be converted 
   string roman; // The return value

   if (part >= 1000)
   {  
      roman = thou_name(part / 1000);
      part = part % 1000;
   }

   if (part >= 100)
   {  
      roman = roman + hun_name(part/100);
      part = part % 100;
   }   
   if (part >= 10)
   {  
      roman = roman + ten_name(part/10);
      part = part % 10;
   }

   if (part > 0)
   {
      roman = roman + digit_name(part);
   }
   return roman;
}





int main() 

{ 

 int n;

 string r;


 n = get_int_ref_checked();

 if (n == 0)
 {

  cout<< "The intput is ZERO! ";

 }

 if(n > 0)
 {

 cout<< "The convert is " << int_to_ROMAN(n); 

 } 

 return 0; 

} 



void get_int_ref_checked(int& n) {
    for(;;) // infinite loop
    {
        cout<< "Please enter an integer\n";
        std::string inp;

        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << inp;
        if( !(ss >> n) || n >= 4000 || n <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Error enter a number n: 0 < n < 4000: \n";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forward declaring the function `int get_int_ref_checked()` but there is no implementation, as `int get_int_ref_checked(int& n)` is another function, which is not being forward declared and so results in the error your seeing.